# What is the value of sys.call() inside an R function? Is it just a vector/list of the function's arguments?

Tags: r, function

My question could also be written: what is the "function call stack"? The help file for `sys.call` makes it clear that that's what it's accessing (which presumably means that that's the value it evaluates to), but it doesn't make clear what that is.

What I'm really trying to do is understand the `rcs` function in the `rms` package. It starts with no default arguments:

```
function (...) {
```

and then immediately stores the value of `sys.call()`:

```
cal <- sys.call()
```

If I run that line alone, then `cal` gets `NULL`. If I run `rcs(x="foo", y="bar")`, what does `cal` get inside the resulting function environment? The equivalent of `list(x="foo", y="bar")`? Or perhaps a named vector of the passed arguments? Or am I thinking about it all wrong?

Comment: Per `?sys.call`: "`sys.call` returns a `call`." See `?call`. Also, perhaps try using `debugonce(foo)` to get inside of the environment of a function as it evaluates to see for yourself in better detail.

Comment: `debugonce` is one of those functions I've been wanting for a long time! Thanks so much. Pointing me to `call` is useful too - does that mean that in my (nonsensical and error-generating) example where I run `rcs(x="foo", y="bar")`, `cal` will be a call object that equals the unevaluated function call `rcs(x="foo", y="bar")`? If so I'd like to accept this as an answer.